# Alternative O(N^2) time complexity with O(1) space complexity for finding distinct values in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, distinct-values

I am trying to see whether there is any alternative to brute force algorithm (or a slight improvement/worst performance to a naive brute force algorithm) that will still result in O(N^2) time complexity and O(1) auxiliary space.

This is my brute force pseudocode:

```
    procedure distinct(Input: array)                             
        for i=0 to i < length of array                      
            for j=i+1 to j < length of array                 
               if array[i] == array[j] and i != j then  
                  return false                        
               end if
               increment k
            end for
            increment j
        end for
        return true
    end procedure
```

I know that brute force algorithm is a terrible solution and there are many ways of achieving much better performance (using data sets or achieving O(N) time complexity and O(1) space complexity), however out of pure interest I am trying to find the O(N^2) worst case time complexity and O(1) space complexity. Is it even possible?

I was thinking that I could possibly apply a sorting algorithm (e.g. Bubble or Insertion sort), then use a for loop to go through sorted array, but would that still give me a quadratic function and not O(N^3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the array using heapsort and stop whenever you find two equal elements:

- O(NLogN) time complexity
- O(1) space complexity

You can also look for other (more advanced algorithms) for this purpose [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Selection and Insertion sort are 2 alternatives with:

- O(NxN) time complexity
- O(1) space complexity

Comment: Thank you for quick response! My question, however, is a very strange one as I am looking for an alternative to precisely O(N^2) time complexity alternative to brute force as opposed to a better solution.

Comment: Selection sort or Insertion sort will do the trick just fine then. Updated the answer.

Comment: great, thank you! I was not too sure whether my thinking was correct in this case!

Comment: Yep, you can pick from that link, any configuration that has O(N^2) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.